# Split text within span if there is an img tag between them - selenium - java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm having a scenario where within a span tag I have two strings, separated by an img tag.

```
<span>
    text
    <img/>
    text
</span>
```

When I'm trying to find this span using selenium and Xpath, I found it - but `getText()` method of the span element returning `"texttext"`. My intention is to get `"text text"`.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("MY_XPATH_TO_FIND_THAT_SPAN").getText();
```

My Xpath is fine (because I'm getting the right web element, but how can I get the string as I note here? I want to append a space whenever there is an img tag.

Will be glad for your help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it using `.getText()`. You can use `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` and then you will need to replace whatever is between the two "text" strings (`IMG`, etc.) with a space.

Here's a simple example based on your HTML that will probably work.

```
String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("MY_XPATH_TO_FIND_THAT_SPAN").getAttribute("innerHTML"); // <span>text<img/>text</span>
s = s.replaceAll("<img.*?/>", " ");
System.out.println(s);
```

This prints

```
<span>text text</span>
```

Comment: How can I split by <img/> tag? Assume that I don't know how many attributes this img tag will contain.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the text **text** from the first child node and the text **text** from third child node you can use the **`getAttribute("innerHTML")`** method and then use [**`split()`**](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-split-method-example/) method and finally print **text text** inserting a space between them accordingly as follows :

```
String my_string = driver.findElement(By.xpath("MY_XPATH_TO_FIND_THAT_SPAN")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String[] stringParts = my_string.split("\n");
String partA = stringParts[0];
String partB = stringParts[2];
System.out.println(partA + " " + partB);
```

Comment: What you suggest in case I don't know the order within that span. I want a solution for both: "text"<img/>"text" and also for: "text"<img/><img/>"text"<img/>"text" and etc... (I don't know in advance the order within the innerHTML, but I know that <img/> tag will separate between text. In addition, there is no assumption that '\n' will be there...