# How to print the specific element in the splitted values in selenium java

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, class, split

```
String ActualValue = element.getAttribute("class");
String[] SplittedValue =ActualValue.split("");
```

**Output:** `object_selected object_notselected`

How to print the value `object_selection` in `System.out.println(" ");`

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials - Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) (See part Creating, Initializing, and **Accessing an Array**)

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions - you'll thank yourself when you're debugging your code in future. Variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Not accepting answers is not something that will help you here

Answer (score 0):

See, this

```
SplittedValue
```

is `string array`, and you can print array in multiple ways:

```
String actualValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//")).getAttribute("class");
String[] splittedValue = actualValue.split("");
    
System.out.println("Length of array:" + splittedValue.length);
if (splittedValue.length > 0) {
    for(String str: splittedValue) {
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Since lenght is zero, split was not properly, you may wanna check what you are passing in split method");
    }
```

Not sure why you are using split like this `split("")`, probably you are looking for this `split(" ")`

Also if you are sure about the string elements, then you can directly print
them like this (Not recommended):

```
String actualValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//")).getAttribute("class");
String[] splittedValue = actualValue.split(" ");
    
System.out.println(splittedValue[0]);
System.out.println(splittedValue[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. Once you retrieve the value of *classname* i.e. *`object_selected object_notselected`* you can invoke [split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184440/split-text-within-span-if-there-is-an-img-tag-between-them-selenium-java/50187490#50187490) with respect to the space character as the delimiter as follows:

```
String ActualValue = element.getAttribute("class");
// ActualValue = "object_selected object_notselected"

String[] SplittedValue = ActualValue.split(" ");

//printing object_selected
System.out.println(SplittedValue[0]);

//printing object_notselected
System.out.println(SplittedValue[1]);
```